# PHP duda como generar un contador en el name de un radio button

Tags: php, jquery, html5, ajax, mysqli

Tengo un panel administrador de encuesta donde agrego, edito y elimino dimensiones y preguntas de la encuesta, a través de esto se aplican las encuesta que contiene 4 dimensiones, en un total de 21 preguntas y con escala de likert.

Mi problema se basa como colocar un contador para que el `name` de cada radio `button` sea diferente adjuntare un ejemplo:

[image: Encuesta]

> La pregunta 1 `name="likert1"`, la pregunta 2 `name="likert2"` y así hasta 
>   pregunta 21 `name="likert 21"`.

Adjunto el código donde hago las consultas

```
<?php
    require 'conexion.php';
     mysqli_query($mysqli,"SET NAMES 'utf8'");

  ?>



  <html lang="es">

  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>




  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <h2 style="text-align:center">Encuesta estudiantes</h2>
        <br>
      </div>





      <?php
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM dimension";
        $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);

        foreach($resultado as $row){


        ?>


        <div class="row table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>
                  <?php echo $row['nombre_dimension']; ?>
                </th>


                <th width="10%">No aplica</th>
                <th width="10%">Muy en desacuerdo</th>
                <th width="10%">En desacuerdo</th>
                <th width="10%">En acuerdo</th>
                <th width="10%">Muy en desacuerdo</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

              <?php   


              $sqlP = "SELECT * FROM preguntas WHERE id_dimension_p=".$row['id_dimension'];
              $resultadoP = $mysqli->query($sqlP) or die (mysqli_error());
                 foreach($resultadoP as $row){
              $likert=0;

              ?>


              <tr>
                <td>
                  <?php echo $row['nombre']; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <center><input type="radio" name='<?php echo $likert; ?>' value="no aplica"></center>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <center><input type="radio" name='<?php echo $likert; ?>' value="muy en desacuerdo"></center>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <center><input type="radio" name='<?php echo $likert; ?>' value="en desacuerdo"></center>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <center><input type="radio" name='<?php echo $likert; ?>' value="en acuerdo"></center>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <center><input type="radio" name='<?php echo $likert; ?>' value="muy en desacuerdo"></center>
                </td>

              </tr>


              <?php }
                $likert++;
            }?>


            </tbody>

          </table>

        </div>

    </div>

  </body>

  </html>
```

**Espero sus orientación o ayudas, de ante muchas gracias**

Comment: esta un poco confuso, necesitas un contador que los diferencie horizontalmente. Podrías publicar algo con el objetivo final que deseas para entender mejor tu necesidad.

Comment: lo que deseo que cada pregunta name="incrementando en uno"
Ejemplo:
pregunta 1 = name "likert1" asi hasta
pregunta 21 = name "likert21"

si el administrador quiere ingresar una nueva pregunta esa seria pregunta 22 y el codigo automatica genere name="likert22"

ojalas se entienda un poco mas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres que **todos** los radio se llamen `likert` + número de la secuencia, empezando por 1:

1. Tienes que modificar el valor de la variable inicial, estableciéndolo a 1:

   ```
   $likert=1;
   ```
2. Tienes que moverla de sitio, colocándola fuera del bucle `for`

   ```
   $likert=1;

   foreach($resultadoP as $row){
         // $likert=0; borrar esto

         //resto del código
   ```
3. Luego, a cada línea aplicas algo así:

   ```
   name='<?php echo "likert".$likert; ?>'
   ```

   Ejemplo, en el caso de no aplica:

   ```
   <center><input type="radio" name='<?php echo "likert".$likert; ?>' value="no aplica"></center>
   ```

   Y así con todos los demás.
4. Tienes que mover el incrementador de `$likert` para que quede dentro del bucle, de ese modo se incrementará en cada iteracción.

   ```
       $likert++;
   <?php }
   ```

Comment: hola
implemente como me dijiste, pero ahora me sale asi:
pregunta 1 : likert 1 
pregunta 2 : likert 2

como pasa al otro ciclo se vuelve repetir 
pregunta 3 : likert 1
pregunta 4 : likert 2
pregunta 5 : likert 3

Comment: Ohhh se me había escapado ese detalle. No obstante, con que inicies `$likert=1;`  antes de esta línea: `foreach($resultadoP as $row){
              // $likert=0;  borrar esto`   y pongas el incrementador dentro del bucle: `<?php $likert++;
 }`  debería funcionar.

Comment: Gracias, si eso era me funciona bien

Answer (score 0):

pon tu variable **$likert** antes del primer `for` y que inicie en **1**

```
$likert=1;
foreach($resultado as $row){
```

modifica la linea que define el `name` en todos sus casos (no aplica, miy desacuerdo etc):

```
<center><input type="radio" name='<?php echo "likert".$likert; ?>'
```

Es todo.

Comment: Muchas gracias
esa era la solución